# Parsing data from DB column

Tags: php, yii

I have a column in a model containing something like that:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:5:"title";i:1;s:6:"tables";i:2;s:7:"figures";}
```

Now in my view I want to generate as many file fields as there are words in the column. So in the case above three fields are going to be generated. I know that I have to use some sort of for each loop but I don't know how to separate the words from the rest of the data.

Comment: [unserialize()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) the data, though it looks corrupted to me

Comment: i would recommend json_decode instead of unserialize though. Unserialization can result in code being loaded and executed due to object instantiation and autoloading, and a malicious user may be able to exploit this.